# Getting the current background operation and handling it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I want to do something when a background operation is completed, I'm using the following code to perform the background operation:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) { () -> Void in
    //perform the background operation
})
```

but from a different view, how can I get the current background operation and handle it?
many thanks :)

Comment: In addition to the answers below, look at `NSOperationQueue`, which wraps GCD in a higher-level API.

Answer (score 4):

One generally doesn't "get the current background operation". If you want to do something when the background operation is completed, you often just put that in the block itself. For example, if you want to update the UI (on the main queue) when the background task is done, you'd do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // perform the background operation

    // now do whatever you want when the above is done

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do whatever you want here
    });
});
```

If you have a series of blocks that you've dispatched to the background, and you want to wait for all of them to finish, you'd generally use a dispatch group:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_queue_t notificationQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    // do something
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    // do something else
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, notificationQueue, ^{
    // whatever you want when the above dispatched blocks finish
});
```

Or you might employ operation queues, and either set a `completionBlock` for a given operation, or create a new operation dependent upon the other operations (which would fire only when the other operations are completed).

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSOperationQueue *completionQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];

NSOperation *operation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do something
}];
[queue addOperation:operation1];

NSOperation *operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do something else
}];
[queue addOperation:operation2];

NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // whatever you want when the above operations finish
}];
[completionOperation addDependency:operation1];
[completionOperation addDependency:operation2];
[completionQueue addOperation:completionOperation];
```

Clearly, all of the above examples are in Objective-C, but the general patterns work equally well in Swift, too.

For more information on asynchronous programming techniques, see the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091). Or refer to [WWDC 2012 video - Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to dispatch another block but on the main queue when the current block finishes.

Only blocks dispatched on the main queue can update UI elements.  If you dispatch a block on the main queue, it will act like a method would.  If you dispatch a block on another queue such that it functions in the background, and then at the end of that block dispatch another block back on the main queue from within your first block, you will be able to invoke any method you want from the second block on the main queue.

Comment: Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'current' background operation. There are arbitrarily many ongoing simultaneously and the block you pass is permitted to complete before `dispatch_async` returns (e.g. your thread gets interrupted in favour of a hardware interrupt or just another thread gaining priority immediately before the return from `dispatch_async` but after your block has been placed into the scheduling queue; your block begins and ends before the thread that dispatched it resumes).

You probably just want to `dispatch_async` back to `dispatch_get_main_queue()` once your operation is complete.